# How to use Flutter to implement a button like ios virtual home button

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a button can move to any position like iPhone Style (Virtual Home Button) in Flutter but I don't know any packages or any library can do it. Moreover, I'd like the button to be able to show along with a specific app, eg. dial-up UI. If I deploy to desktop, will its behavior the same with mobile?

[image]

**ios virtual home button**

[image]

**show button along with dial-up UI**

Hope you guys help me ways to create it.

I have tried with unicorndial, floating_bubble, popup window, etc.
but all of them are widget within flutter app, instead of system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you can't really create anything like that outside of your App context. Apple is very strict in situations like this.

You can implement this sort of feature in `Android` by using Floating `Service`. But for Apple it's a **NO NO**.

Comment: How about MacOS, can I implement the same?

Comment: @nonew I have never tried anything on `macOS` yet but I have a strong feeling, it wont' work there too.